# Iterate on string enum

Tags: node.js, typescript

I must be missing something, but I found several ways to iterate through an Enum but not on a string enum.

**The following enum is given:**

```
export enum Locales {
  En = 'en',
  Fr = 'fr',
  De = 'de',
  Es = 'es',
  It = 'it',
  Nl = 'nl',
  No = 'no',
  Tr = 'tr',
}
```

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to iterate on that string enum so that I get the values (!). What I've tried:

```
for (const key of Object.keys(Locales)) {
  const locale: string = Locales[key];
  console.log(locale); // Should print 'en', 'fr' and so on
}
```

**The problem with above code:**

Due to the strict tsconfig (which doesn't allow implicit anys) I can not compile this to javascript. Since this is not my project I can not change this tsconfig either. It highlights the `key` variable at `Locales[key]` and the error makes sense to me:

> [ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is
>   not of type 'number'.

**The question:**

What's the proper way iterating through a string enum to get it's values with Typescript 2.6+?

Comment: Using - keyof typeof Locales -  will give a type that is an enumeration of the enum members, that type can be used to assert the type of the key - Locales[key as keyof typeof Locales].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Artem and @betadeveloper pointed out that I can use the `keyof typeof Locales` type for my approach. The solution I eventually came up with looks like this:

```
const keys: (keyof typeof Locales)[] = <(keyof typeof Locales)[]>Object.keys(Locales);
for (const key of keys) {
  const locale: string = Locales[key];
  console.log(locale); // Prints 'en', 'fr' and so on
}
```

Comment: If the old-style `for .. in` loop still works as artem mentions, why not use it? I would suggest to avoid ugly C++-like type casting whenever possible.

Comment: As mentioned it is not my project and hereby it's also not my tslint. We are using microsoft's contrib tslint, which can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib . In the past I noticed there is usually always a good reason for their ruleset, so I prefer to stick to these rules as well. What I am doing above is literally the same as artem suggested just the Typescript 2+ style & following the microsoft tslint guidelines.

Comment: It's quite a pain, I wish it was easier, but this works great

Comment: `<>` casting also seems to be discouraged by `no-angle-bracket-type-assertion` TSLint rule in Angular 9. You can also drop the type hint, since type will be inferred. This way first line turns into: `const keys = Object.keys(Locales) as (keyof typeof Locales)[];`, which doesn't look that bad and keeps linter happy.

Comment: This answer came like an angel in my life...Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

As betadeveloper suggested, you can get proper type for key if you use type assertion `as keyof typeof Locales`. Or you can wrap it in type-safe variant of `Object.keys()` function like this:

```
export enum Locales {
  En = 'en',
  Fr = 'fr',
  De = 'de',
  Es = 'es',
  It = 'it',
  Nl = 'nl',
  No = 'no',
  Tr = 'tr',
}

function enumKeys<E>(e: E): (keyof E)[] {
  return Object.keys(e) as (keyof E)[];
}

for (const key of enumKeys(Locales)) {
  const locale: string = Locales[key];
  console.log(locale); 
}
```

Also, for the record, old-style `for .. in` loop still works:

```
for (let key in Locales) {
    let locale = Locales[key];
    console.log(locale);
}
```

Comment: I was told I should never use `for in` loops, and so the project's tslint configuration is now unhappy. `[tslint] for (... in ...) statements must be filtered with an if statement (forin)` and `[tslint] Do not use the 'for in' statement: 'for (const key in Locales)'. If this is an object, use 'Object.keys' instead. If this is an array use a standard 'for' loop instead. (no-for-in)`. Also I don't see how this would help me as I'll have the same issue (having a string for the index) as well there? In my given example I also tried to cast `key` to a string, which wouldn't change anything ofcourse

Comment: It helps (if it were not for your `tslint` config) because it compiles without errors in strict mode.

Comment: Ok agreed on this, however I am surprised that typescript compiles this. locale is in your case just another string (just like in my given example). Can you explain why typescript compiles your example while it wouldn't compile my code (which also uses a string as index)?

Comment: No idea how to explain it, probably because the compiler infers proper type (`keyof typeof Locales`, not `string` ) for `key`  in `for .. in ` loop. @betadeveloper suggestion is even better - I'm updating the answer

Comment: Betadeveloper's approach doesn't work. Keyof Locale is a string[]. I am still trying to crack that nut with your given input. I am really disappointed that it's apparently so hard to iterate on a string enum :(. `[ts]
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '(keyof E)[]'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof E'.` Edit: I think I made a mistake at refactoring my code to the Typescript 2 version (no `as` casting).

Comment: `keyof typeof Locales` works, `keyof Locales` does not.

Comment: Wow I've never used such a typecasting, but that's what I was missing. Using this type casting my approach also does work. I just have to cast the `Object.keys()` before.

Comment: `enumKeys(Locals).map(key => ...)` AWESOME! the key is now a string literal :)

Answer (score 3):

**Lodash**

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/) is a good option to use since it is easy to use and provides a easy to understand api. From the lodash methods, [forIn](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#forIn) is the option you're looking for. To get [typescript declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html), you can install:

`npm install @types/lodash`

With the [forIn](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#forIn) method, you get the *value* and the *key* of `Locales` object.

```
import { forIn } from 'lodash'

enum Locales {
  En = 'en',
  Fr = 'fr'
  // ...
}

forIn(Locales, (value, key) => console.log(value, key))
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to this question because I was looking for a solution.

The best solution is to use `Object.values()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

```js
Object.values(Locales).forEach((locale) => console.log(locale));

// or

for (const locale of Object.values(Locales)) {
  console.log(locale);
}
```

Also consider `Object.entries()` to get both the keys and values of a string value enum.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const entries = Object.entries(Locales);
  let LocalesArray= [];
  entries.forEach((type) => {
    LocalesArray.push({ key: type[0], name: type[1] });
  });
```

Simple way to iterate over enum values and convert them into object array.