# Using enum in generic for router

Tags: typescript, generics, enums

I have an enum with a list of routes.

```
enum ServerRoutes {
  WHISPER_SECRET = 0,
  SHOUT_SECRET = 1,
  SHOUT_SECRET_MULTIPLE_TIMES = 2
}
```

**I'd like to create a ServerRouter that has compile-time guarantees that every route is handled. I'd like to do this using a generic so that I can later on create a ClientRouter**

```
type Router<T> = { [route in keyof T]: () => void }
type ServerRouter = Router<ServerRoutes>;
```

So far so good. Everything above compiles fine. However, when I try to actually implement a ServerRouter, I get an error. Here is the code that generates the error:

```
const serverRouter: ServerRouter = {
  WHISPER_SECRET: () => {},
  SHOUT_SECRET: () => {},
  SHOUT_SECRET_MULTIPLE_TIMES: () => {}
}
```

And here is the error:

```
Type '{ WHISPER_SECRET: () => void; SHOUT_SECRET: () => void; SHOUT_SECRET_MULTIPLE_TIMES: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'ServerRoutes'.
```

Unfortunately, the error doesn't really explain what the problem is other than "not assignable". How can I either fix my code or use another strategy to acheive the same goal?

Comment: Did my answer help? Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Enum under the hood creates sophisticated structure which, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47896885/iterate-on-string-enum), not so easy to iterate. This structure looks like this:

```js
(function (ServerRoutes) {
    ServerRoutes[ServerRoutes["WHISPER_SECRET"] = 0] = "WHISPER_SECRET";
    ServerRoutes[ServerRoutes["SHOUT_SECRET"] = 1] = "SHOUT_SECRET";
    ServerRoutes[ServerRoutes["SHOUT_SECRET_MULTIPLE_TIMES"] = 2] = "SHOUT_SECRET_MULTIPLE_TIMES";
})(ServerRoutes || (ServerRoutes = {}));
```

In your case try use class instead of enum and it will work fine. I've created example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=6#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCmAnAbkgSgewK4Bd4wG8AoaaAdQAkBJWABQFE0B9WegYTXoBVoBeaAAwk4FAPIBVLi3ace-AIzDYYydI7cmAWXEAZLlVo76TfZvqw+0AExEAvkSI4AngAd40TLiQAeLgD5LAmgAbURsPGgASwA7aABreCcMADNoLgBdAC5oAAoASj4A5AxIgBNoe2c3OCRURE88REsGnwQUdHD8PwBuB2AMaIgcaAhajq9EbLa6lqb+YlJyajpGNVls-MLoINsAGiUVKVZ1Lg2C3gCCPYOJI5kNbT0DIxMqM1gzrau7IA)

```js
class ServerRoutes {
  WHISPER_SECRET = 0
  SHOUT_SECRET = 1
  SHOUT_SECRET_MULTIPLE_TIMES = 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20965) you are not the first to want to use keyof with an array, and it looks as though there is still not a clean solution in TypeScript to get what you are looking for.

However, alternatively you could create an interface to specify the contract for your serverRouter e.g.

```
type RouterFunction = () => void

interface IServerRouter {
  WHISPER_SECRET: RouterFunction
  SHOUT_SECRET: RouterFunction
  SHOUT_SECRET_MULTIPLE_TIMES: RouterFunction
}

const serverRouter: IServerRouter = {
  WHISPER_SECRET: () => {},
  SHOUT_SECRET: () => {},
  SHOUT_SECRET_MULTIPLE_TIMES: () => {}
}
```

You can see this code in this TypeScript [Playground Link](http://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2BATgMQQOwMbAJZyZQC8UAFAJQkB8UAbnHgCYBQLemyKAZgIbbQAkgGVUdVPCSooAbxZQoAdQASIgAoBRGAH1hGgMIwNAFQBcsRFww58heVGHKA8gFVjug0bMWp6LLgJMe0dXdz1DE20AWRcAGWNBNViNbQSojWFzSSt-WyCAXzZsQgBnYCgSsQlLVHMRKpRs6VI5BRV1LQ8I70oaWSh8gBpg5zcur3Ne4loZIZHQ8ciY+MTk1MF0zPIqadlC-KA).

This approach is explicit and does not require the specification of redundant numeric values like you have in an enum(!).